# CMake: Linking libraries during build?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I am new to CMake and I am attempting to link libraries that are generated in the same project. The (simplified) project structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Library1
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── include
│       └── foo.h
│       └── bar.h
│   └── src
│       └── foo.cpp
│       └── bar.cpp
├── Library2
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── include
│       └── baz.h
│   └── src
│       └── baz.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17.0)
project(MyProject)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

add_subdirectory(Library1)
add_subdirectory(Library2)
```

Library1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Library1)

add_library(library1 
    src/foo.cpp 
    src/bar.cpp
)

target_include_directories(library1 PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1/include
)
```

Library2/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Library2)

add_library(library2 
    src/baz.cpp
)

target_include_directories(library2 PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library2/include
)

find_library(LIB1 library1 HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1)

target_link_libraries(library2 PUBLIC LIB1)
```

If I run `cmake MyProject`
I'll get this error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. 
LIB1 
    linked by target 'library2' in directory 'MyProject/Library2'

--- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed. Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

How do I link `library2` to `library1` when the `library1` target won't be generated until after `cmake --build MyProject`? Or is this not the correct way to be structuring this project?

Comment: Just link library using its **target** name: `target_link_libraries(library2 PUBLIC library1)`. CMake will understand that `library1` corresponds to the target created in the same project, and will apply all needed dependencies, properties, usage requirements automatically. This works wherever library1 target is already created or will be created later.

Comment: When I go to link, its looking in ```/usr/bin/ld``` and not in my source tree for the library? I tried adding the source tree using directory using ```link_directories``` but it doesn't work

Comment: Actually, your output doesn't correspond to the code: in the code you link `library2` target in the `Library2/CMakeLists.txt`, but your output refers to the library `library1` linked in the `Library1/CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is wrong.

```
find_library(LIB1 library1 HINTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1)

target_link_libraries(library2 PUBLIC LIB1)
```

In the project you have presented you do not need to `find` any library. It's already part of your build.

To fix your problem just link the library:

```
target_link_libraries(library2 PUBLIC library1)
```

TLDR explanation of when to use `find_*` commands:

CMake offers a host of `find_*` commands that are useful when working with package managers, SDKs, etc. that have installed `pre-built` binaries on your computer.

In this case it's not needed since `library1` is already part of your project. Why would CMake need to `find` something it created/defined?

Comment: It seems I am now getting an error when linking: ```/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibrary1``` Do I need to set some environment variable to tell the linker to look in the project source tree?